# how to change border length of the input field?

Tags: html, css

i have an image and border in my input field and i want that there were no border below image. Any ideas? the image should be after border but inside the input field

```
<input type="text" />

input{
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    background-image: url("");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
```

Comment: I'm lost. In your code you set `border-bottom`, but write you want no border...

Comment: Your title asks how to change your border length, your body text talks about 'no border'. Which is it? - [edit] your question.

Comment: This question requires some clarification and a working example. As far as I understand it @lesek wants a border under the `input` but _not_ below the `background-image` set on the `input`.

Answer (score 0):

The `border-bottom` and `border-top` takes the `width` of the element to which it is a border.

Changing the `width` of the `input` should change the `width` of it's `border`.

[Here it is in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/gulfarazyasin/6a380g73/)

You can change the `width` in the CSS to see the change in length.

Comment: but the image is moving with the border and i want it to be after border but inside the input field

Comment: try `background-position: top left;` instead of `right`